# php authentication id_token code error: origin parameter is required

Tags: php, android, authentication, google-plus

I build an android app using google plus signin. After signin, mainActivity get token code and send it to php server, my php server will use code to verify and get access token from google. If success, php server store access token in a session and allow android client load data from server into android app.

But i have a problem with php-googe-library:

In android app, I use the follow code to get token:

```
String token = null;
        Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
        appActivities.putString(
                GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES,
                Constants.ADD_ACTIVITY_SCHEME);

        String serverClientID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
        String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + serverClientID
                + ":api_scope:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;

        // String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this,// Context
                    mPlusClient.getAccountName(), // String accountName
                    scopes, // String scope
                    appActivities // Bundle bundle
                    );
            Log.i("TAG", "token" + token);
        } catch (IOException transientEx) {

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            Intent recover = e.getIntent();
            startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
            Log.w("Loi xay ra NeedPermission", e.getMessage());

        } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {

        }
        return token;
```

After receive token, i post it to my php server use this method:

```
public static String postTokenToWebServer(String url, String data) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", data));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = resEntity.getContent();
        String result = StringUtil.convertStreamToString(is);

        return result;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return "ClientProtocolException";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "IOException";
    }
}
```

I received the code on my php server. I call **authenticate($code)** method of google client to authenticate code for access token, use follow codé:

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php";

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId('MY_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('MY_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
$client->setDeveloperKey('MY_DEVELOPER_KEY');    
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    session_start();
    $mToken = $_POST['code'];
    echo "Token code is: $mToken";
    $client->authenticate($_POST['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();   

}
```

But, I receive an error: **invalid_request origin parameter is required!**, whole are:

```
Lỗi:invalid_request
origin parameter is required!

Tìm hiểu thêm
Chi tiết yêu cầu
    response_type=code
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
    redirect_uri=postmessage
    access_type=offline
    approval_prompt=force
    client_id=648976189452-lgujem37fatd8cnlrn1uicp81q0tgfn7.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I have read and try many way to fix this issue, but still not work. how can i fix it. Help.